# Regex to python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a lot of file names with the pattern `SURENAME__notalwaysmiddlename_firstnames_1230123Abc123-16x_notalways.pdf`, e.g.:

- `SMITH_John_001322Cde444-16v_HA.pdf`
- `FLORRICK-DOILE_Debora_Alicia_321333Gef213-16p.pdf`
- `ROBINSON-SMITH_Maria-Louise_321333Gef213-16p_GH.pdf`

My old regex was `([\w]*)_([\w-\w]+)\.\w+` but after switching to Python and getting the first double-barrelled surnames (and even in the first names) I'm unable to get it running.

With the old regex I got two groups:

1. `SMITH_James`
2. `001322Cde444-16v_HA`

But now I have no clue how to achieve this with `re` and even include the occasional double-barrelled names in group 1 and the ID in group 2.

Comment: post the code that you are using so we can help you :)

Comment: I'd recommend using e.g. https://regex101.com/#python to develop the regex. It gives you explanations of your pattern and visual demonstrations of what it currently matches.

Comment: Really, `[\w-\w]`? What would be the purpose of the this "range"? Try [`(\w*)_([\w-]+)\.\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/4mEALO/1). However, I am not sure what the output should be. If you use it with `re.findall`, it will only return a list of tuples. Use `re.finditer` to get all match objects to access any match data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`([A-Z-]+)(?:_([A-z-]+))?_([A-z-]+)_(\d.*)\.`

This pattern will return the surname, potential middle name, first name, and final string.

- `([A-Z-]+)` returns a upper-cased word that can also contain `-`
- `(?:_([A-z-]+))?` returns 0 or 1 matches of a word preceded by an `_`. The `(?:` makes the `_` non-capturing
- `([A-z-]+)` returns a word that can also contain `-`
- `(\d.*)` returns a string that starts with a number
- `\.` finds the escaped period right before the file type

Comment: Regex answers are more useful if you include an explanation of how they work.